# Memory Stream in C++ using type declarations

Tags: c++, memory, stream, iostream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there binary memory streams in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559254/are-there-binary-memory-streams-in-c)

Oops - [Are there binary memory streams in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559254/are-there-binary-memory-streams-in-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559254/are-there-binary-memory-streams-in-c ?

Comment: Oh wow, that certainly didn't show up on the search. I apologize!

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I need an easy-to-use class which I can load raw data into and stream it into different variables

That would be IO streams. You can use their `.read()` and `.write()` member functions to read and write binary data.