# a write function throwing the exception of read access violation in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I tried writing to a file and I am unable to write to it due to "Access violation reading location 0x0000000F" I am able to isolate the problem here is the sample code:

```
void test_1() {
    std::fstream fio{ "xyz.dat",std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app };
    if (!fio) {
        std::cerr << "sorry no file";
        return;
    }
    std::string s_test{ "xyz hii \n workf" };
    fio.write( ( char* )(s_test.length()), sizeof( size_t ) );  //the write causing issue
}
```

Comment: `( char* )(s_test.length())` is treating the size as though it's a pointer. Sort of like `(char *) 10`. As soon as write tries to use the memory at 10, [The Bad](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) happens and the program probably goes Ka-BOOOM! Based on the error message, the length of the string is 15.

Comment: Why so many tagged versions of C++?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492259/writing-binary-data-to-fstream-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`( char* )(s_test.length())` is treating the length of the string as though it's a pointer and passing address 15 into `write`. Since there is no valid character at address 15, this triggers [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), and the behaviour in this case is the program crashes.

This is always a problem when forced to use such a wide cast to force re-interpretation of a type. You can screw up horribly and all the compiler's defenses have been turned off. I don't have a good solution for this.

You need to pass in a legitimate address containing the length for `write` to operate on. To get this, you'll need to create a variable you can take the address of. `&s_test.length();` isn't good enough here because you cannot take the address of a [prvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) returned by a function.

```cpp
auto len = s_test.length();
fio.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&len), sizeof( len ) );
```

Note that writing a variable of automatically deduced type or a variable of a type that can change between compiler implementations is risky. It's hard to be sure how many bytes you're going to need to read at the other side.

```
uint32_t len = x.length();
```

Would be safer, and probably more compact, but at the risk of overflow with strings greater than 4.4 billion characters in length. That's a risk I'm willing to put up with.

Another concern is [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It's not as common a problem as it used to be, but both the writer and reader need to agree on the byte order of the integer. `htonl` and `ntohl` can help mitigate this threat by guaranteeing a byte order.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to write the length of the string to your output file, you can do it like this:

```
size_t len = s_test.length();
fio.write( ( const char * ) &len, sizeof( size_t ) );
```

Comment: thanks and nicely pointed out, but I would like to add that  using a cstdint would be better since it wont change its size across x64 compilers. I know I made that mistake in the first place but the other answer helped me understand.