# Failed to unarchive file which compressed by c++ zlib.h

Tags: c++, compression, gzip, archive, zlib

Compress string (i tried to compress file but it didnt help) and save compress data to file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <zlib.h>

int main() {
    char a[50] = "Hello, world!";
    char b[50];

    uLong ucompSize = strlen(a)+1;
    uLong compSize = compressBound(ucompSize);

    compress((Bytef *)b, &compSize, (Bytef *)a, ucompSize);

    std::ofstream f;
    f.open("res.txt.gz", std::ios::binary);
    f.write(b, compSize);

    // Assertion
    char c[50];
    uncompress((Bytef *)c, &ucompSize, (Bytef *)b, compSize);;
    assert(std::string(c) == std::string(a));
}
```

Next Im trying to unarchive it by gzip util and error appears:

```
$ gzip -d res.txt.gz 

gzip: res.txt.gz: not in gzip format
```

Where is the compression error?

Comment: Your minimal example appears to have several typos. Also you have to write a binary file and not a text file. And `b` is not a null terminated string.

Comment: @drescherjm I added `std::ios::binary` to opening file but it still doesn't work

Comment: You need to fix `f << data;`  you cant use `<<` you need to use `f.write()` and make sure that you use `compSize` as the size to write.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing binary data to fstream in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492259/writing-binary-data-to-fstream-in-c)

Comment: @drescherjm not completely. I need to understand how write char array

Comment: `f.write(b, compSize );`

Comment: @drescherjm its still doesn't work :(

Comment: `std::ios::app` is wrong in that if you had a corrupt archive from previous tests it will append to that and still be corrupt.

Comment: @drescherjm remove `std::ios::app`. still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

It says it's not in gzip format because it's not in gzip format. `compress()` compresses to the zlib format. If you want zlib to produce gzip streams, you either need to use `deflate()` to do it in memory, or the `gz*` functions if you're writing to a file.